# Navbar in Header JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

EDIT: My temporary solution is to turn off all transitions and use different id for each header. You then get the persistent toolbar, but without transitions. 
[working example without transitions](http://jsfiddle.net/9ASRg/)

I am using a persistent fixed navbar in my header in JQuery Mobile. 
I'm navigating between 3 html files, and on the first(main) page there is no problem, but on the second and third page the navbar covers some of the content.

example of broken navbar code for the navbar and header:

```
<div data-role="header" data-id="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
        <a href="options.html" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Options</a>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="top"class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"  >Page1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="top"  >Page2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page3" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="top" >Page3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /header -->
```

I have uploaded an example of the problem here(with pages in one html file instead of three html files) : [broken navbar](http://jsfiddle.net/LvuUX/)

Comment: The strangest thing is that when I clicked "Inspect element" in my Opera, the `<ul>`s jumped down and behave just as you expect them to. What a sorcery :-o And no, I haven't found anything wrong with the CSS yet...

Answer (score 1):

here's the updated one:
http://jsfiddle.net/LvuUX/2/

You had same `data-id="header"` for all three pages, as you are using `multi-page template` so you can't have same `id` for `multiple elements`

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/LvuUX/3/
looks like jQuery is not using the correct `padding-top` when page loads. To fix this issue you can just use a fix `padding-top` for your `data-role="content"`

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-page-header-fixed { padding-top: 5.9em; }
</style>
```

Comment: Altough this solves the problem you end up losing the persistent toolbar which was what I was trying to to in the first place. I don't think multi-page template is the issue, in my app I don't use that anyways. In the Jquery documentation they actually say you have to have the same id on the header to make it persistent.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is similar to the problem I had. I had a fixed positioned navbar but my page content was being hidden underneath it. I solved the problem by applying a top margin to my content div equal to the height of the navbar. (ie. My margin-top of my content div was 50px as that was the height of my navbar.)

[Fixed positioned elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) are removed from the normal flow. The document and other elements behave like the fixed positioned element does not exist.

I hope I interpreted your question correctly. I've only been learning html&css 3 months but when I saw your question I thought this might help.